# Coroutines the proper way to add a job as child of another?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

Given we have `job1 : Job` and `job2 : Job` and we want to make `job2` a child of `job1` (they where created separately have no relation).

What is the correct way to declare that relationship? so that when `job1` is cancelled `job2` is cancelled as well...

I tried `job1.attachChild(e1.job2 as ChildJob)` but this is internal api.
I do not want to do some hack when i launch job2 from job1 coroutine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `Job(parent: Job?)` factory function which receives parent job as a parameter. It has the following definition:

```
public fun Job(parent: Job? = null): Job
```

that means parameter **parent** is an optional.
So you can create your jobs like this:

```
var parentJob: Job = Job()
var childJob: Job = Job(parentJob)
```

Also take a look at [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html), which can be used to customize the default behavior of the [`Job`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html). `SupervisorJob` factory function has similar definition:

```
fun SupervisorJob(parent: Job? = null): Job
```

Comment: Yeah i've found this soon after the question, but still sucks that there is no way to connect two jobs.

Comment: You can also obtain the Job of the current scope like this `val parentJob = currentScope.coroutineContext[Job]`

Answer (score 2):

Simply launch job2 from inside the scope of job1. Job2 will inherit the scope, and so if job1 is cancelled then so is job2.

Comment: that sucks, that makes me do some weird stuff just to ensure a simple parent child relationship... there should be some better way.